# Empty Response Web Service Doctrine 2 Slim 3

Tags: php, foreach, doctrine, slim

There is happening something really freaky, The following code is from a request I have in my Web Service using Slim 3 and Doctrine 2, I am geetting a empty response, I know for a fact the array it's getting filled but it is returning empty!

```
    $data = $request->getParsedBody();

    $intervention_items = $this->em->getRepository('App\Entity\V_Interventionitems')
            ->findAll(array('ic_interventiontype_id' => $data['it_id']));

    foreach ($intervention_items as $int_items){
        $data_response[] = $int_items->toArray();
        //echo json_encode($int_items->toArray()); here prints the info right
    }

    return $response->withStatus(200)
        ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        ->write(json_encode($data_response)); //here returns empty
```

I know this issue is very amateur but I am invoking the Knoledge of my friends to help me out ;)

Comment: What does var_dump($data_response) output?

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode($data_response)` is returning `false`. Use `json_last_error()` to find out what is wrong.